# How to trigger an AWS Event Rule when a S3 key with a specific suffix gets uploaded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge, amazon-cloudtrail

I'm trying to create an AWS Event Rule that is only triggered when a file with a specific suffix is uploaded to an S3 bucket.

```json
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject",
      "CompleteMultipartUpload"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "bucket-name"
      ],
      "key": [
        { "suffix": ".csv" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As I understand there AWS has content-based filtering which can be used but docs doesn't show the ability to use a suffix, only prefix among other patterns: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html

Ideally I could be able to do it here without the need for an intermediary Lambda as my event target is an ECS Fargate task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that suffix matching has been added

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-suffix-matching

Therefore, the example given in the question is now valid!

Answer (score 6):

At this time (July 2020) CloudWatch events **does not** appear to have suffix filtering built into it.

You could instead configure an [S3 Event Notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-filtering) which do support the ability to specify prefixes and suffixes.

By using an S3 event notification you can still have your target as a Lambda.

Comment: Hi Chris, my target is actually an ECS Fargate task and I do **not** want to have an intermediary Lambda.

Comment: @AaronZhong at the moment there is no option to use suffixes with content filtering (its relatively new) for CloudWatch events. Hopefully in the future we'll see this added. The alternative is to have all the files you'd want to pass in a specific prefix so that you can then have your fargate task as a direct target.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Do we have this feature now to add suffix in cloudwatch rule?

Comment: my only concern is that my target is getting triggered event if a new empty folder is created. I just want to avoid this.

Comment: You could go S3 event -> SNS -> Eventbridge -> Fargate

Comment: @Merlin though it will work but my AWS cost will increase quite a bit as I do not want 500 million messages extra SNS to be added every month

Unbelievable they do not support proper filtering -  do they want people to use less filters so more events get fired and more money they make?

Comment: @Sun Maybe there is a difficulty in how filtering is implemented. At any rate, you could use a prefix like `s3://yada-yada/csv/path/file.csv` and land all of your CSV files into a prefix containing 'csv'.  Possibly also tagging the object in the upload could be a trigger.